# Como puedo pasar el valor de una variable a la funcion update de sqlite3 en python

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3

Quisiera saber como pasar datos a la función update de sqlite 3:

este es el código:

```
conexion = sqlite3.connect("Db/Users.db")
cursor = conexion.cursor()
intem = self.lineEdit.text()

cursor.execute('UPDATE Usuarios SET Contraseña ='intem' WHERE ID = 1')

conexion.commit()
conexion.close
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto utiliza una estructura similar al `.format()` para las string. Concretamente, para sqlite3 se utiliza `?` como valor a reemplazar por datos.

**Ejemplo:**

```
cursor.execute('UPDATE Usuarios SET Contraseña = ?, Otracosa = ? WHERE ID = 1',
              (intem, otracosa))
```

El primer parámetro de `execute` es la consulta a la base de datos, el segundo parámetro es un Tuple con nuestros datos reemplazando cada `?`. Es importante que mencione que al ser un tuple obligatorio, si solo quieres pasar un único valor tienes que seguir haciéndolo en un Tuple:

```
cursor.execute('UPDATE Usuarios SET Contraseña = ? WHERE ID = 1', (intem,))
```